# How to have timer with variable duration in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I make a timer that its speed increases every minute i.e. the timer duration decreases evey 1 minute in Flutter?

Comment: use [Timer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Timer/Timer.html) constructor (each time decreasing `duration`), not `Timer.periodic`

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Perhaps an example!

Comment: you call a `Timer` with 60 sec `duration`, when `callback` completes you call it again with 58 sec, then with 56 etc

Answer (score 1):

You could make just one `Timer.periodic` with your minimum period and use a static counter in the callback to mark off multiples of that variable period. This has the advantage of being easily extended to any number of tasks running at different periods -- all driven by the same timer.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';

const int minPeriod=1;
const int maxPeriod=10;
const double decreaseRate=0.1;

int variablePeriodSeconds(int t) {
  var p=decreaseRate*t;
  return max(maxPeriod-p.floor(),minPeriod); // simple linear decrease
}

void main() {
  int tTick=0;
  int tTock=0;
  final Duration minDuration = Duration(seconds: minPeriod);
  Timer timer = Timer.periodic(minDuration, (Timer timer) {
  print('tick');
  if(tTick-tTock >= variablePeriodSeconds(tTick)){
      print("TOCK!");
      tTock=tTick;
  }
  tTick++;
  });
}
```

The above code creates an explicit `tTick` counter, but the Timer object has an instance variable `timer.tick` that's pretty much good to go for this same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

As say in the comments section, you can have a recursive function to do the works.

```dart
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  launchTimer(Duration(seconds: 2), minDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300));
}

void launchTimer(Duration duration, {Duration? minDuration}) =>   Timer(duration, () {
    final wantedDuration = duration - Duration(milliseconds: 300);
  
    if (minDuration != null && wantedDuration < minDuration) {
      print('minDuration');
      launchTimer(minDuration, minDuration: minDuration);
    } else {
      print('wantedDuration');
      launchTimer(wantedDuration, minDuration: minDuration);
    }
});
```

In this example, I had a `minDuration` limit, to avoid unwanted behavior.

You can import this code into a dart pad to try this out :)

Comment: Thx. I believe this would do. So in this case, if I want to stop the timer if a condition is made, then I do not call the launchTimer function anymore, right? I do not need to used any timer.cancel() here as the timer is not periodic.

Comment: Just one more point, why the limit is 300 milliseconds. I think I have seen this number somewhere else if I am not mistaken. Can't we go to smaller duration value? I want this timer to update the statefull widget via setState. So you think I should not go to smaller value than 300 milliseconds? The main reason for all this is because I want to go to smaller duration values than 300 milliseconds!

Comment: You can put whatever duration you want, it's just an example :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `Timer` implementation that acts like a normal periodic `Timer` but allows the callback to modify the period (and even the callback):

```dart
import 'dart:async';

class VariableTimer implements Timer {
  void Function(VariableTimer) callback;
  Duration period;
  Timer? _timer;
  int _tick = 0;

  VariableTimer(Duration initialPeriod, this.callback)
      : period = initialPeriod {
    _timer = Timer(initialPeriod, _onTimer);
  }

  @override
  bool get isActive => _timer != null;

  @override
  int get tick => _tick;

  @override
  void cancel() {
    _timer?.cancel();
    _timer = null;
  }

  void _onTimer() {
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch()..start();
    _tick += 1;
    callback(this);
    if (!isActive) {
      return;
    }

    var adjustedPeriod = _max(Duration.zero, period - stopwatch.elapsed);
    _timer = Timer(adjustedPeriod, _onTimer);
  }
}

Duration _max(Duration duration1, Duration duration2) =>
    duration1 >= duration2 ? duration1 : duration2;
```

Example usage that creates a periodic `Timer` that initially fires every 10 seconds, firing one second sooner each minute, and stopping when the period reaches 0:

```dart
void main() {
  const oneMinute = Duration(minutes: 1);
  var nextUpdate = DateTime.now().add(oneMinute);
  VariableTimer(const Duration(seconds: 10), (timer) {
    print(DateTime.now());
    
    var timeToNext = nextUpdate.difference(DateTime.now());
    if (timeToNext <= Duration.zero) {
      nextUpdate = nextUpdate.add(oneMinute);

      timer.period -= const Duration(seconds: 1);
      if (timer.period <= Duration.zero) {
        timer.cancel();
      }
    }
  });
}
```